# How is group by multiple conditions using aggregate function?

Tags: r

I have database with data fram [454,712 x 16] as picture below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTjJ1.jpg)

I would like to group data by **Code** and **Gen** which want to **count** #rows and **sum** of premium.

My code is >`tmp <- group_by(data, Code, Gen)`>`summarise(tmp, count=n(), sum(TOT_ANN_PREMIUM))`

Results is correct as my expected.

If I would like to use aggregate function, How should I do?
I know only `aggregate(data$TOT_ANN_PREMIUM, by=list(data$Code), FUN=sum)`

Or should I use summarise_each function?
Please give me some advices.

Comment: perhaps: `aggregate(TOT_ANN_PREMIUM~Code*Gen, data, sum)`

Comment: Thank you. But it is nearly correct. There is no counting of data (row).

Comment: Like this: `aggregate(mpg~gear*carb,mtcars,function(x) c(S=sum(x),L=length(x)))`

Comment: Try `group_by(data, Code, Gen)  %>% summarise(count=n(), sum(TOT_ANN_PREMIUM))`. It is always helpful to add some data in the question instead of a screenshot. You can use `dput()` for that.